# At startup, open the specified ViewController (iOS)

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, nsuserdefaults

I have two VCs (**ViewController, SettingsVC, VC2**).

How can I make it so that when you turn on the switch (located in `SettingsVC`), when the application starts, it would show VC2?

The default is **ViewController.swift**.

I tried this code but when I turn on the switch, nothing happens after the restart.

**SettingsVC.swift**

```
let isSwitchOn = UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "isSwitchOn")

 @IBOutlet weak var `switch`: UISwitch!
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let isSwitchOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "isSwitchOn")
    if isSwitchOn {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let VC2 = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
        self.window!.rootViewController = VC2;
    }
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not change the `UserDefaults` value when the switch changes. You should connect the following `IBAction` to **Value Changed** in IB:

**SettingsVC.swift**

```
@IBAction func switchValueChanged(_ sender: UISwitch) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(sender.isOn, forKey: "isSwitchOn")
}
```

Comment: When the application is launched, only the VC that is written in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions